# Create a sample login page using servlet and JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I developed a sample login page for validating username and password. If the user gives correct credentials the page will navigate to some other page, else return a message from the `servlet` to the same login page.

I have enclosed the sample `code` here:

#### FirstJSP.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>`
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Login" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="Name"/><br>
            <input type="password" name=Pass><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/><br>
            <%if(request.getAttribute("message")!=(""))
            out.println(request.getAttribute("message"));
            else
            out.println("");%>
            <h1>Hi This is JSP sample code </h1>
            <font color="blue" size="25">
            <marquee>Please login to Work with JSP</marquee></font>
            <%java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); %>
            <h1>Current Date: <%= df.format(new java.util.Date()) %> </h1>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And `servlet` code, Login.java:

```
package com.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public Login() {
        super();
    }
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("Name");
        String password = request.getParameter("Pass");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        if(username.equals("sugan") && password.equals("raj")) {
            response.getWriter().println("<html><body><Marquee>Welcome to JSP!!!</marquee></body></html>");                
        } 
        else {                
            String message = "OOps!!! Invalid Username/Password";
            request.setAttribute("message", message);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/FirstJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);                
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but while loading the login page it automatically displays `Null`. Then if the user gives the wrong credentials, it displays the actual message. How do I disable the `Null` message during run time?

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the message with the empty string using `==`.

First, your comparison is wrong because the message will be null (and not the empty string).

Second, it's wrong because Objects must be compared with `equals()` and not with `==`.

Third, it's wrong because you should avoid scriptlets in JSP, and use the JSP EL, the JSTL, and other custom tags instead:

```
<c:id test="${!empty message}">
    <c:out value="${message}"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Hi JB I used .equals() method but that also throws some exception like "NullPointerException"

Comment: Yes, because as I said in point 1: the message will be null. Not the empty string. Your test should be `if(request.getAttribute("message") != null`. If you had to compare it against the empty string, you should use `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really using the doGet() method. When you're opening the page, it issues a GET request, not POST.

Try changing doPost() to service() instead... then you're using the same method to handle GET and POST requests.

...

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are comparing the message with the empty string using ==.

Its very hard to write the full code, but I can tell the flow of code - 
first, create db class & method inide that which will return the connection.
second, create a servelet(ex-login.java) & import that db class onto that servlet.
third, create instance of imported db class with the help of new operator & call the connection method of that db class.
fourth, creaet prepared statement & execute statement & put this code in try catch block for exception handling.Use if-else condition in the try block to navigate your login page based on success or failure.

I hope, it will help you. If any problem, then please revert.

Nikhil Pahariya