# How to call a function with parameters in a java file from a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

i have the `emp.java` file with method as

```
    boolean create(int empid,String empname,int supid );
```

i have the `register.jsp` page as

```
 <form name="register" action="#" method="post">
        <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Employee Id</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="empid"
                                        placeholder="Enter Employee Id " size="30"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Employee Name</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="empname"
                                        placeholder="Enter Employee Name " size="30"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Supervisor Id</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="sup_id"
                                        placeholder="Enter Supervisor Id" size="30"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="justify"><input type="submit"
                                        value="Submit"></td>


                                </tr>
                                </table>
    </form>
```

**My requirement** is as i click the submit button the `emp.create()` must be called with the parameters entered in the `register.jsp` page.... Is there any way to solve this?
What are the necessary things which i have to change so that i can reach my requirement!

or is there any way that i can pass my values to the employee-->create(employee e)

```
....
{
 callableStatement = openConnection().prepareCall("{call insert_employee(?,?,?)}");
                callableStatement.setInt(1,employee.getempid());
                callableStatement.setString(2,employee.getempname());
                callableStatement.setInt(3,employee.getsupid());    
}
...
```

as a `object(*)` all values when i click submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This into the RegisterDao.jsp file

```
<%          Object function_name(call the function of the callable stmt) = new Object();
        int empid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("empid"));
        String empname = request.getParameter("empname");
        int supid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("supid"));

        int status = function_name.method(empid, empname, supid);

        if (status > 0) {
            //out.println("Employee is created");
    %>//jsp code to display if he is te employee
<%
        session.setAttribute("session", "TRUE");
        } else {
            out.println("Creation failed");
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a servlet class which will call your emp.java classes' method. The servlet class should work as your action for register.jsp. In the servlet you can do request.getparameter/attribute()and collect the values of input types using their name/id.

Pass these values to either a method or callable anywhere you want to use. If you want to stay on the same jsp after your processing then you need to use ajax.

Comment: You can use any servlet example for that sake. 
Try the one in this question. change the parameters to get values from your request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981191/create-a-sample-login-page-using-servlet-and-jsp
Please upvote or accept as answer if this helps u.

Comment: This is the basic servlet example. http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm

Comment: thank u .. but is there any way to call the function with parameters(String,String) directly from a jsp page!!without using a servlet..

Comment: You can write in scriplets. Create object of your java class and call the method and pass the parameters using getparameter but i m not sure how you will call it on submit.

Answer (score 0):

create a bean which should have getter and setter methods of the fields that accepts inputs in the register page
and also inside the bean create your method

```
boolean create(int empid,String empname,int supid );
```

now you form action should call a another jsp and it should have these methods in the head

```
<jsp:useBean id="" class=""></jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: i have tried in this way !! but i cant make it work ! i shall keep the code pasted in a link and send u back

Comment: `<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>

<jsp:useBean id="register" class="bean.LoginDao" scope="session">
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="register" />`
</jsp:useBean>

Comment: but i cant able to retrieve those values..inorder to call the `LoginDao {

 public static boolean validate(String email,String pass){...}`

Comment: @user2561626 no need to write <%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%> because you are already using  <jsp:useBean id="register" class="bean.LoginDao" scope="session">

Comment: ok fine!! but the problem raised is i am unable to send a object from .jsp page to the java file..

Comment: what happened exactly is the LoginDao ha 2 parameters and i am unable to retrive those values by using <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="register">...

Comment: its too long to paste it in here!! is there ant jsp fiddle to post!!

Comment: @user2561626 you can call the methods in jsp by wrting <% register.(method name) %>
if you are using eclipse IDE then just type register. within the scripllets and it will give the method names and after that call it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33897/discussion-between-user2561626-and-java-programmer)